# How to Pivot Only a select number of rows

Tags: sql, pivot

I am new to SQL and have a question. I have the following data:

```
Name            Description     Format

John            An Old Man      M
Mary            An Old Woman    F
Smith           A Boy           M
Doe             A Girl          F
Carry           Sister          F
Kevin           Brother         M
Joe             Cousin          M
Anne            Cousin          F
```

I need it to come out looking like the following. Is it possible?

```
Name1   Description1 Format1 Name2 Description2 Format2 Name3 Description3 Format3

John    An Old Man    M      Mary  An Old Woman  F      Smith  A Boy       M 
Doe     A Girl        F      Carry Sister        F      Kevin  Brother     M 
Joe     Cousin        M      Anne  Cousin        F
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using.

Comment: Have you looked at all the questions tagged [sql and pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)?

Comment: I have looked at other posts about pivoting, but they seem to have a column that indicates an order that the data needs to follow. (For example, so many people in a car and you can use the car to identify what records go on what row. I do not have such an indicator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  But the trick is some arithmetic to get the names in groups of three:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then description end) as description_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then format end) as format_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then name end) as name_12
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then description end) as description_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then format end) as format_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then name end) as name_3,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then description end) as description_3,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then format end) as format_3
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by name) - 1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum / 3;
```

Comment: . . .  It doesn't produce desired result. (`partition by name order by name`).

Comment: I do not have a column that specifies the ordering. I just want three records to read in a single row and then the next three in a row after that. I am also using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.I hope that that helps.

Comment: @AndreaParker . . . I see.  I misunderstood the question at first.